# Why the pointer in linked list is of structure type?

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists

Since any node points to a memory location is there any specific need in using it's pointer as *structure* type.Why couldn't we use integer as the pointer type in linked list rather than structure?

Comment: What is the context of your question? A specific course? A specific programming language? What nodes are you talking about?

Comment: This seems to be a programming question to me.  Please clarify how this is a computer *science* question, if it is.

Answer (score 2):

The nodes in a linked list need to hold two things:

- the node's value
- a (possibly null) pointer to the next node

That makes them structs, so a pointer to a node is a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an untyped pointer if you wish, but the advantage of having a pointer to a structure is type safety – it helps you protect yourself from misusing the pointer. When implemented in machine code, the pointer is indeed untyped.

It's not a terribly good idea to implement a pointer as an integer, however, since the sizes of both are implementation dependent and could differ. On your system a particular type of integer has the same size as a pointer, but on another system that same type of integer has a different, perhaps smaller, size. Sometimes you even have to worry about several types of pointers.

Comment: :Do you mean to say that a structure pointer is implementation independent?I would like to know whether we could use an _integer pointer_ instead of a _structure pointer_ in **linked list**?

Comment: This also depends on implementation, though I imagine it's always the same kind of pointer. But why would you want to use the "wrong" kind of pointer? It's not type safe and works against you as a programmer.

Comment: :Just curious to know whether there is any specific difference between _structure pointer_ and _integer pointer_ other than the notion that "both points to a memory location".

Comment: There *could* be. It could be implementation-dependent in a given programming language. You're not necessarily promised that they are the same. For example, it might happen that integers and structures are stored in different parts of memory.

Comment: :Does the _structure pointer_ has anything additional compared to _integer pointer_?

Comment: No, it just stores a memory address. But when you use it, the programming language assumes that it points to a structure.

Comment: :yeah that's right.